# Equivalence of categories preserves (co)products

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $A$ and $B$ be categories with (arbitrary) products and coproducts and $F : A \rightarrow B$ is an equivalence of categories, then $F$ preserves limits and colimits, hence $F$ preserves arbitrary products and coproducts. Here is my question:

Can we prove that if $F$ is an equivalence, then $F$ preserves (arbitrary) products and coproducts without using limits and colimits?

Thank you!

Comment: Take the proof that $F$ preserves limits and colimits, and restrict to the case where they are products/coproducts.

Comment: Yes. It's very helpful to use the fact that a functor is an equivalence of categories if and only if it is full, faithful and essentially surjective on objects. (But then all you're really doing is repeating the general proof for (co)limits in the case of (co)products.)

Comment: @CaptainLama thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It may also be nice to know that every equivalence can be promoted to adjoint equivalence. This can be done in a symmetrical fashion, hence both $F$ and $G$ are both left and right adjoints.

This implies the wanted.